# Extending Protocols With Default Implementation with Enums crashes Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift, enums, protocols

I've been playing with protocol extensions and come up with something I think may be an error, or may be a misunderstanding on my part.

Say you have some special animal abilities and an animal protocol:

```
enum Ability {
    case Flying
    case Running
    case Swimming
    case Hiding
}

//All animals will conform to this
protocol Animal {
    var name: String { get }
    var specialAbility: Ability { get }
}
```

So you define your animal struct:

```
struct Dog: Animal {
    var name: String
    var specialAbility: Ability
}
```

But then you need to define an ability each time you want a dog:

```
let rex = Dog.init(name: "Rex", specialAbility: .Flying)
```

So then you want a default implementation of the `specialAbility`:

```
extension Animal where Self: Dog {
    var specialAbility: Ability { return .Running }
}
```

But then Xcode crashes. It complains "Communication with the playground service was interrupted unexpectedly."

Answer (score 0):

The issue is when trying to extend `Animal where Self: Dog`. Dog is a struct, not a protocol so `where` will not work.